# Como colocar várias séries em 3 dimensões em um highchart corretamente?

Tags: c#, webforms, highcharts

Meu objetivo é criar um gráfico onde eu tenho o nome, a quantidade e o período.

Estou usando o DotNet.HighChart em C# WebForms.

Meu gráfico atualmente está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu até sei porque está assim, só não estou conseguindo consertar.

Este erro se dá pelo seguinte:

Cada série desta está vindo de uma consulta só, porém cada consulta desta foi utilizado da formula group by para juntar as datas e quando ele vai plotar as séries ele pega a ultima e aplica para tudo.

O meu código é este:

```
    public string TentativaNovoGrafico()
    {
        ProjetoBLL projBLL = new ProjetoBLL();
        Projeto proj = new Projeto();

        List<Tuple<string, int, string>> massivos = projBLL.GrafQtdMassivosAno();

        object[,] chartDataMassivos = new object[massivos.Count, 3];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (Tuple<string, int, string> item in massivos)
        {
            chartDataMassivos.SetValue(item.Item1, i, 0);
            chartDataMassivos.SetValue(item.Item2, i, 1);
            chartDataMassivos.SetValue(item.Item3, i, 2);
            i++;
        }

        List<Tuple<string, int, string>> repAtivos = projBLL.GrafQtdRepAtivosAno();

        object[,] chartDataRepAtivos = new object[massivos.Count, 3];
        int j = 0;

        foreach (Tuple<string, int, string> item in massivos)
        {
            chartDataRepAtivos.SetValue(item.Item1, j, 0);
            chartDataRepAtivos.SetValue(item.Item2, j, 1);
            chartDataRepAtivos.SetValue(item.Item3, j, 2);
            j++;
        }

        List<Tuple<string, int, string>> especiais = projBLL.GrafQtdEspeciaisAno();

        object[,] chartDataEspeciais = new object[massivos.Count, 3];
        int k = 0;

        foreach (Tuple<string, int, string> item in massivos)
        {
            chartDataEspeciais.SetValue(item.Item1, k, 0);
            chartDataEspeciais.SetValue(item.Item2, k, 1);
            chartDataEspeciais.SetValue(item.Item3, k, 2);
            k++;
        }

        Series serieMassivos = new Series();
        Series serieEspecial = new Series();
        Series serieRepAtivos = new Series();

        serieMassivos.Data = new Data(chartDataMassivos);
        serieEspecial.Data = new Data(chartDataEspeciais);
        serieRepAtivos.Data = new Data(chartDataRepAtivos);

        serieMassivos.Name = "Massivos";
        serieEspecial.Name = "Especial";
        serieRepAtivos.Name = "Rep. de Ativos";

        serieMassivos.Type = ChartTypes.Column;
        serieEspecial.Type = ChartTypes.Column;
        serieRepAtivos.Type = ChartTypes.Column;

        Series[] series = new Series[] { serieMassivos, serieEspecial, serieRepAtivos };

        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("bar").SetTitle(new Title
            {
                Text = "Quantidade Projetos"
            }).SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories =
                    new[]
                        {
                            "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"
                        }
            })

    .SetSeries(series);

        return chart.ToHtmlString();
    }
```

Comment: Boa tarde @Marconi eu queria fazer um deste http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Comment: Na verdade meu html é só: <asp:Literal ID="grafico1" runat="server"></asp:Literal> e o meu return deste método que eu mandei acima preenche esse literal e mostra o grafico

Comment: É este ai no tópico poxa. É nele que eu em alguma parte estou errando.

Comment: Entendi cara, achei que vc estava usando Ajax tbm. Era bem mais facil de fazer com Ajax.